# Hide html overflow after opeping modal window

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog

After opening modal window, visible 2 scrolls (html and modal). 
I want to hide html overflow , and do visible after closing modal window. 
How do this without js? only by css

```
$('.modal').on('show', function() {
    $("html").css({
        overflow: 'hidden'
    });
});

$('.modal').on('hide', function() {
    $("html").css({
        overflow: 'scroll'
    });
});
```

Comment: May I advice you to add a working demo using code tags, [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [embeded StackOverflow Code Snippet](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) of your HTML/CSS code you wrote so far to increase chances to get a anwser.

Comment: How would you know that the modal is open or closed. Are you using bootstrap modal or something?

Comment: Yes, i`m using bootstrap modal. I wrote function like in description. It works, but i wont do this by css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct event triggers for the Bootstrap's modal are `'show.bs.modal'` and `'hide.bs.modal'`

Try this instead:

```
jQuery('.modal').on('show.bs.modal', function() {
    jQuery("html").css({
        overflow: 'hidden'
    });
});

jQuery('.modal').on('hide.bs.modal', function() {
    jQuery("html").css({
        overflow: 'scroll'
    });
});
```

But I strongly advise you to use the Bootstrap's method to show/hide a modal. It handles the HTML overflow automatically.

```
jQuery("#element").modal('show');
jQuery("#element").modal('hide');
```